# How to fix maven dependency scope conflicts (runtime-compile-provided)?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, exec-maven-plugin

I have a project where I use multiple dependencies. I'm used to execute my code in a dev environment using

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass="my.Main"
```

That worked fine until I recently started using a dependency (let's call it `A`) that defines its own dependencies with the runtime scope. One of its runtime dependencies (let's call it `B`) is actually a dependency to another dependency of mine that I set with a `provided` scope (let's call it `C`).

So I have

```
MyProject depends on A[compile] who depends on B[runtime]
MyProject depends on C[provided] who depends on B[no-scope-specified]
```

I end up having `B` considered as a runtime dependency which results in a `ClassNotFoundException` when I launch the above command. The only solution I found is adding a `dependencyManagement` entry that forces its scope to compile.

That bothers me as I do not directly use that dependency (I have no reference to it in my code) so I should not have to bother with it.

**Is there some way to avoid that kind of conflict and maybe load all dependencies in the classpath when using `mvn exec:java`?**

Thanks

Comment: What happens, when you change exec.classpathScope=compile to exec.classpathScope=runtime?

Comment: I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on some class contained in my provided dependency.